# Momentjs comparing full ISO string not working

Tags: momentjs

momentJS comparing in full ISO string never works

```
moment("2021-08-11T19:22:000+08:00").isAfter("2021-08-11T17:22:000+08:00", "minute") // false
moment("2021-08-11T15:22:000+08:00").isAfter("2021-08-11T17:22:000+08:00", "minute") // false
moment("2021-08-11T15:20:000+08:00").isAfter("2021-08-11T17:50:000+08:00", "minute") // false
moment("2021-08-11T19:22:000+08:00").isAfter("2021-08-11T17:16:000+08:00", "minute") // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
moment("2021-08-11T19:22:000+08:00").isAfter("2021-08-11T17:22:000+08:00", "minute") // false
```

sorry my bad. formatting error. missing `seconds` values

```
moment("2021-08-11T19:22:000+08:00") // incorrect
moment("2021-08-11T19:22:00.000+08:00") // correct
```